# WORDPRESS: How to identify media by title instead of ID in a gallery

Tags: wordpress, gallery, media

I'm working on a mass upload of images and gallery posts, so I would like to prepare my posts offline.
The gallery code is `[gallery  include="94,104"]` where the ID numbers are assigned by WP at uploading time.

It would be a big help to modify the gallery script so media could be referred by `post_title`,`post_name` or `guid`, so the post content can be prepared without knowing the ID. Ideally, I would like to do: `[gallery  include=" IMG_4736.jpg"]`.

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to identify a media element by its file name.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects to this, first you can find media elements by the title with an instance of the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class, or you can use [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). Set the post type to attachment and of you go.

Secondly to use the titles as the identifiers in the shortcode you are going to need to

```
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'my_function' );
```

This will allow you to alter the way files are selected and presented for the shortcode. See the [source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/media.php#L658) for what is output ordinarily.

I must say, it seems a strange approach - the ID is the best way to uniquely identify an item (what if you get two images with the same title?). You know you can add a gallery using the 'Add Media' button and that will insert the ID's for you? - just checking :)

Comment: I will look into your suggestions. Thanks. I'm preparing some large gallery posts, with over 100 images. The online editor is not suitable. My plan is to upload images zipped and import posts in xml. Addressing images by name lets me prepare the postings without having to find out the assigned ID of each image.